# To show marker icon on image based on its x,y coordinates in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I'm learning coding in angularJS. I need to show a marker or icon over an image when it is clicked. Based on the (x,y) coordinates of image when i click the image i need to show a marker icon on the specific coordinate.

I've add my sample code in plunker. [`\[https://plnkr.co/edit/ZKf0ydN35k5y20zgor48?p=preview\]\[1\].`](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZKf0ydN35k5y20zgor48?p=preview) Check in log. the x,y coordinates will be displayed for each click event on image.

Can anyone please help me regarding this.

Comment: please share some code or provide a plunkar!

Comment: I've updated my question and added the sample plunker code. I'm getting the coordinates in log. but i need to add a marker icon on image for each click event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **ng-style** to update the style of your marker on mouse click:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>ng-click in AngularJs</title>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.1/angular.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('ngClickCtrl', ["$scope", function ($scope) {
          $scope.obj = {};
          $scope.obj.myStyle = {};
            $scope.img=function(event){
              var x = event.clientX;
          var y = event.clientY;
          var coords = "X coords: " + x + ", Y coords: " + y;
          console.log("coords--"+coords);
          $scope.obj.myStyle["left"] = event.clientX+'px';
          $scope.obj.myStyle["top"] = event.clientY+'px';
          console.log($scope.obj.myStyle);
      }
        }]);
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="ngClickCtrl">
       <img  src="https://www.timeshighereducation.com/sites/default/files/small-uni.jpg" ng-click="img($event)"/>
       <img style="width:20px;position: absolute;" ng-style="obj.myStyle" ng-if="obj.myStyle != {}" src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/Map-Markers-Icons-Demo-PNG/128/Map-Marker-Marker-Outside-Chartreuse.png" id="marker" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks a lot. Yor solution works for me. But I'm not getting the marker icon at exact position where we are clicking. It appears little far from where the click event occurs

Comment: @NandhniB you have to consider the width of your marker and make adjustment according to in the style.

Comment: how can we convert these coords into percentage to it will work on all screens?